# Do HID interrupts interrupt all devices?

Tags: usb, hid, hidapi

I am writing code for a very specific scientific device (a spectrometer) for Windows. This device registers itself as an HID device. A library and source code of the library for the device has been provided.
Going by the source code, the device gets a request from the host and responds with data using the INTERRUPT IN endpoint. The hidapi library is used for HID data transfer. I noticed that using the hidapi's `hid_read_timeout` function, my computer's input devices as well as audio (connected by USB) freeze for short timeperiod (maybe 200 ms) everytime the request for data is sent and read (every time `hid_read_timeout` is called). I'm currently trying to understand the USB HID specifications, but my question is why this happens. Does the interrupt interrupt everything on all USB ports? If so, is there a way to prevent it? What would occur if I had multiple devices and would call `hid_read_timeout` multiple times sequentially? Would these calls block each other?

Answer (score 0):

In the context of a USB endpoints, "interrupt" just means that you get a guarantee about how often you can send data with that interrupt.  There's no reason for your use of interrupt endpoint on one device to disrupt the use of other devices.  It sounds like you might have found a serious bug in Windows, if that's really happening to you.

Comment: I also believe there is no bug in Windows but that I am rather doing something wrong. Thanks for confirming that. I also never noticed any other usb devices causing this (if I understand correctly, if interrupts were to interrupt other USB devices, then reading from a USB would also freeze keyboard/mouse and audio, which is not happening). Unfortunately I don't know what even to look for to fix my issue. I found documentation about the HID spec, but none about how it is implemented. I thought using hidapi would be straightforward.